# How handle a button in typescript in dynamic code

Tags: angular, typescript, smartadmin

I'm working with the [Smart Admin Angular Version](https://bootstraphunter.com/theme/smartadmin-responsive-webapp-frontend-BSH01), When I want to use from notificationService I have a problem.

I cant handle pressed button in notificationService.smallBox.

My code in like bellow:

```
notificationExample5() {

  this.notificationService.smallBox({
    title: "Ding Dong!",
    content: "Someone's at the door...shall one get it sir? <p class='text-align-right'><a href-void class='btn btn-primary btn-sm'>Yes</a> <a href-void class='btn btn-danger btn-sm'>No</a></p>",
    color: "#296191",
    //timeout: 8000,
    icon: "fa fa-bell swing animated"
  });
}
```

How I cant handle 'YES' or 'NO' button in Angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have multiple ways to achieve it.

try https://stackoverflow.com/a/43065100/8179245 already answered solution.

Or use this stackbliz created for you https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-confirmation-dialog-1i8zgw?file=app/app.component.ts

### App Component Ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { ConfirmationDialogService } from './confirmation-dialog/confirmation-dialog.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  constructor(private confirmationDialogService: ConfirmationDialogService) {}

  public openConfirmationDialog() {
    this.confirmationDialogService.confirm('Please confirm..', 'Do you really want to ... ?')
    .then((confirmed) => console.log('User confirmed:', confirmed))
    .catch(() => console.log('User dismissed the dialog (e.g., by using ESC, clicking the cross icon, or clicking outside the dialog)'));
  }
}
```

### App Component HTML

```
<button (click)="openConfirmationDialog()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Open dialog</button>

<p>Open the console to see log statements.</p>
```

### Confirm Box TS

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbActiveModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-confirmation-dialog',
  templateUrl: './confirmation-dialog.component.html',
})
export class ConfirmationDialogComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() title: string;
  @Input() message: string;
  @Input() btnOkText: string;
  @Input() btnCancelText: string;

  constructor(private activeModal: NgbActiveModal) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  public decline() {
    this.activeModal.close(false);
  }

  public accept() {
    this.activeModal.close(true);
  }

  public dismiss() {
    this.activeModal.dismiss();
  }

}
```

### Confirm Box HTML

```
<div class="modal-header">
  <h4 class="modal-title">{{ title }}</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="dismiss()">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    {{ message }}
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" (click)="decline()">{{ btnCancelText }}</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="accept()">{{ btnOkText }}</button>
  </div>
```

### Confirm Box Service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

import { ConfirmationDialogComponent } from './confirmation-dialog.component';

@Injectable()
export class ConfirmationDialogService {

  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) { }

  public confirm(
    title: string,
    message: string,
    btnOkText: string = 'OK',
    btnCancelText: string = 'Cancel',
    dialogSize: 'sm'|'lg' = 'sm'): Promise<boolean> {
    const modalRef = this.modalService.open(ConfirmationDialogComponent, { size: dialogSize });
    modalRef.componentInstance.title = title;
    modalRef.componentInstance.message = message;
    modalRef.componentInstance.btnOkText = btnOkText;
    modalRef.componentInstance.btnCancelText = btnCancelText;

    return modalRef.result;
  }

}
```