# Dialog in Angular without Component

Tags: angular, dialog

Is there a way in Angular 8 to generate a small dialog without having to create a new Component? Some small message like "Operation completed" that wouldn't require much interaction with the user. I just feel like having 4 more files in a project just to display a success message would be too much:

```
small-dialog.component.html
small-dialog.component.scss
small-dialog.component.spec.ts
small-dialog.component.ts
```

Or maybe there's a way to create a "default component" in few lines without having to actually *generate* a new component?

Comment: What's your use case for not wanting to create a new component? To me this is the perfect example of when to create a reusable component?

Comment: How exactly do you want to open the dialog?

Comment: I tried to explain better in my original post, check it out!

Comment: Answered here! https://stackoverflow.com/a/67264069/12834967

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you don't want to create component for dialog itself you can do something like this:

View.html

```
<button (click)="openDialog(template)">Open my dialog</button>
<ng-template #template>
 <h1>This is a message</h1>
</ng-template>
```

Component.ts

```
import {MatDialog, MatDialogRef} from '@angular/material/dialog';

 
constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) {}

openDialog(templateRef) {
  let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(templateRef, {
   width: '300px'
 });
}
```

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-template-mat-dialog?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)
is also one example how you can do the same thing.

But I propose to you that you create generic dialog component which you can use through the whole application, how to get started with that you can see it [here](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2017/11/13/easy-dialogs-with-angular-material.html).

**Update**:
How to create a dialog without Material components can be seen [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qw9kku?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! How should I define `this.dialog`? And what if the data I want to display is just a string? Sorry but I'm really a beginner in Angular :)

Comment: @Robb1 you can use the overlaymoduke of angular CDK

Comment: And without Material ?  The question doesn't ask for Material Design to be loaded into the project.